# Simple Javascript question about "if" condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
if (selectedCountry == "USA") {
  $("#state").show();
}
```

How can I change name for my div #state with the same condition? 
(to add `name="NewName"` to my `div id="state"`)

Smth like:

```
if (selectedCountry == "USA") {
  $("#state").show();
  $("#state").name("NewName");      <-- ?
}
```

Comment: `name` of `div`? Any reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (selectedCountry == "USA") {
  $("#state").show();
  $("#state").attr("name","NewName");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set attributes on an element, for this:

```
if (selectedCountry == "USA") {
  $("#state").show().attr("name", "NewName");
}
```

If setting many at once, you can also pass an object, for example:

```
if (selectedCountry == "USA") {
  $("#state").show().attr({ name: "NewName" });
}
```

I'm *assuming* you meant a `<select>` here with a dropdown, since a `<div>` won't be serialized into a form a `name` attribute isn't useful or valid, if this isn't the select, just find the form element and perform the same `.attr()` call.